# Load Random Data into HTML from JSON File?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, random

When I design interfaces, I can't be bothered to create believable dummy text. At the same time, however, I don't want to just copy and paste the same exact data over and over, because then the interface doesn't look terribly realistic.

I have generated a [Master JSON Schema](https://www.mockaroo.com/37dcc3b0/download?count=1000&key=37b5a7c0) that contains the most common types of data I use. I'd like to be able to do something like this when I'm writing HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>{first_name}</li>
  <li>{first_name}</li>
  ...
  <li>{first_name}</li>
</ul>
```

**OR**

```
<ul>
  <li data="{first_name}"></li>
  <li data="{first_name}"></li>
  ...
  <li data="{first_name}"></li>
</ul>
```

...whereby every instance of `{first_name}` is replaced with a random first name from my JSON file. Likewise for any other variable I have in there ( `last_name`, `email`, `address`, `country`, `sentence`, etc... )

Is there a way to do this **without PHP** in something like jQuery? I imagine it'd have to be something like:

```
foreach(var) {
  return randomData(var);
}
```

Ideally I'd have a very simple, generalized function that would comb through the UI looking for any and all tags and replace each one with a random piece of data from the master schema JSON file.

---

### Click below to see solution I came up with thanks to Billy's help:

http://jsfiddle.net/JonMoore/5Lcfz838/2

Comment: You could use `Math.random` and then just grab the random index of your json array

Comment: Not sure how I'd write a short, generalized function to comb through the UI, look for any tags in braces (or in the "data" attribute of a tag...however I should do it), then replace each one.

Comment: AJAX is your friend here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

between http://chancejs.com/ and http://handlebarsjs.com/ you can generate lots of repeatable, seeded random data structures...

```js
// get references to DOM elements
var tplElm = document.getElementById('template');
var tgtElm = document.getElementById('target');

// compile handlebars template
var template = Handlebars.compile(tplElm.innerText);

// initialise chance with seed
// change the seed to change the output data
var chance = new Chance(1234567890);

// create array of random data
var people = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  people.push({
    first_name: chance.name()
  });
}

// apply data to template, and insert into page
tgtElm.innerHTML = template({
  people: people
});
```

```html
<!-- load dependencies -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chance/0.5.6/chance.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<!-- define template -->
<script id="template" type="text/template">
<ul>
  {{#people}}
  <li>{{first_name}}</li>
  {{/people}}
</ul>
</script>

<!-- placeholder for output -->
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Exactly the type of thing I was looking for. Thank you, Billy!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will give you what you want:

```
var json = [{ "first_name": "bob"}, {"first_name": "sam"}, {"first_name": "bill"}];
var randomnum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));
console.log(json[randomnum].first_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access this data using AJAX and then get elements using `Math.random`.
Then, with the help of jQuery you can dynamically generate `li` items.

Let's suppose you have a div element like `<div id="anyId"></div>` where you will put your `ul` and `li`s.

```
function getElementsFromMasterSchema(count, callback) {
  var items = [];
  var usedIds = {};

  $("h3").text("Request sent...Loading..."); 
  timer = setInterval(function() {
      $("h3").text("Loading..." + (time++) + " seconds passed.");           
  }, 1000);

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.mockaroo.com/37dcc3b0/download?count=100&key=37b5a7c0",
    method: "GET"
  }).done(function(dt) {
    var length = dt.length;

    while (items.length < count) {
      var randomItem = dt[Math.round(Math.random() * length)];
      if (usedIds[randomItem.id] !== true) {
        usedIds[randomItem.id] = true;
        items.push(randomItem);
      }
    }

    callback(items);
  });
}

getElementsFromMasterSchema(10, function(result) {
  var ul = $("<ul/>");

  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    $("<li/>").text(result.first_name).appendTo(ul);
  }

  $("#anyId").append(ul);
});
```

Note that you need to make requests from the same domain or set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in order to make cross-domain requests.

**However**, this method is working slowly. It takes from 5 to 20 seconds to load this file. Loading a large file from a server and using only some of data is a bad approach.
You definitely need to implement this algorithm on a server side. Something like SQL `SELECT TOP n FROM x ORDER BY newid()` (`SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT n`).

Comment: Will this comb through the HTML to identify all tags like {first_name} and {last_name} and return an appropriate random value?

Comment: @Jon It will not identify anything. You should do everything yourself. However, I have shown how to do this in my updated answer.